# How can I join elements obtained from html parsing done in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have multiple html files that look like the following.

```
<footnotes>
    <footnote id="F1">content1</footnote>
    <footnote id="F2">content2</footnote>
    <footnote id="F3">content3</footnote>
    <footnote id="F4">content4</footnote>
</footnotes>
```

Note that the number of footnote ids in different html files can be different ranging from 0 to several hundreds. 
I want the ids and contents to be appeared in the same cell in csv file having "/" as partition.
That would be look like "F1 content1/F2 content2/F3 content3/F4 content4"

The below code is all I have.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'htmparser') #Let's say doc has the html.
    Footnotes = soup.select('footnotes')
    Footnotes = '/'.join(Footnotes)

writer.writerow(Footnotes.text)
```

The difficult part is parsing ids and contents and joining them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `id` from an element with `BeautifulSoup`, you can look at the `.attrs` property, which is a dictionary. For the text, you know about `.text`. Hence:

```
cell = '/'.join(f"{f.attrs['id']} {f.text}" for f in soup.select('footnote'))
writer.writerow([cell])
```

Notes: the `f""` syntax comes with Python 3.6. For older versions, use:

```
"{} {}".format(f.attrs['id'], f.text)
```

also, this supposes all footnotes have an `id` attribute.

Comment: I think you want join in there? OP wants single cell output of / separated pairs so / would also be the delimiter between pairs. Add [id] to selector to ensure id present i.e. footnote[id]

Comment: well, from the python3 doc (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) `writerow` takes an array, so it should work. But this will create one column per footnote... Is it what OP wants ? Not clear to me...

Comment: Thanks for the help, Derlin. It gives me something, but not exactly. The code you wrote appear as "F1/content1", "F2/content2", and so on. And each "Fn/contentn" is written in the consecutive cells. I want those to be in single cell just like "F1 content1/F2 content2".

Comment: oh ! hence the join @QHarr was talking about. Didn't get that, sorry. Updated my answer.